# Create self contained GUI installer from ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, devops

Ansible is a great tool to install and update software on servers. It is usually part of CI/CD workflow.
However some customers want manual control on when software updates to a new version.

So the questions is: Is it possible to pack Ansible, some playbook, and all required files into self contained GUI (or console) installer which would ask all required params from hosts.yml and a server login and runs playbook on against single server? What tools can be used for that purpose?

Comment: I've never used it but probably what you're looking for is Ansible Tower: https://www.ansible.com/products/tower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for in AWX (or Tower) but this is a web service for running playbooks the way you describe.

You can have it hosted but I can assure you that nobody is going to make and “exe”. My guess that that those asking for that feature have no clue about what configuration management means and nothing will make them happy.

Is like asking for car for travelling from one island to another.

Still, id you want to provide a click interface and forms for parameters, AWX/Tower are exactly what you are looking for.

Now I only hope you are not asking about a GUI installer for them!!!

Comment: I do know what configuration management means and use it for years. My playbooks contains rather simple tasks and I do not know any showstopper that would prevent packing ansible into gui package. I just understand there is a lot of work to implement it and not everyone can use such solution